# How to handle Object References in Entity?

Tags: android, android-room

I have the following structure to save to app database:

```
@Entity
public class Project{
   @primaryKey
   String id;
   String name;
   [...]
   Country country;
   [...]
}
```

And my Country Entity looks like the following:

```
@Entity
public class Country {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String pk;
}
```

Now to my Question: How do I make Room know the Relation between Country and Project Entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room can not have nested entities, you can embedd POJO classes in an entity but it will get flattened into a single table or if you want Country as an entity then you'll have to store county_id in Project entity and index it as foreign key.

More on Embedded fields: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded.html

More on Foreign key: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ForeignKey.html

Comment: The part with the ForeignKey I had in mind, too. But how would I populate the Country Entity? Especially how should the Country Class know about the Project id?
In my Case I'm recieving a JSON with a lot of different informations and nested arrays etc. And my Mapper populates the Entity classes recursively.
Maybe there is just one little thing I'm missing...

Comment: You'll first need to populate the Project entity using ProjectDao and then extract the country_id in the project object then use that id to populate Country object. You can also create a POJO class to extract data from both table. To understand why room doesn't allow nested entity, read this: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data.html#understand-no-object-references

Comment: Thank you! I think I will get along with your answer.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the official documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html